# Javascript getting value of input type text

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to write a simple code. The program will alert the type of the device "input or output". this is the code:

```
<h1>Input or output device?</h1>
device name: <input type="text" id="device">
  <br><br>
    <script>
      const x = document.getElementById("device").value;
      </script>
    <button onclick='alert(x === "mouse" ? "input device":"output device")'>Check now</button>
```

Comment: anything I type gives me output device even when I write mouse.

Comment: I want even to add more devices names to the condition and I do not know how

Comment: `const x = document.getElementById("device").value;` is executed exactly once when the page loads ... so `x` is a constant empty string - you could `const x = document.getElementById("device")` then check `x.value`

Comment: So what can I use instead?

Comment: I just told you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the `<script>` executes only once when the page loads - therefore, the value of `x`  is going to be fixed during the existence of the page. This is the reason why `x` doesn't change when anything is typed.

There are many solutions. One would be to add `onChange` event to the input.

```
<input type="text" id="device" onChange="inputChanged()">

<script>
   var x;
   function inputChanged() {
     x = document.getElementById("device").value;
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Refer to this question for doing the same without `getElementById` inside the function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119541/passing-this-object-as-argument-in-onchange-event